# Not able to use nodeSelector PodSpec in OPA

Tags: open-policy-agent

I want to add policy that node Selector should exists in pod.
I have made the below code not able to wrap my head around the issue with this as not able to get desired output.

```
package kubernetes.admission
deny[reason] {
input.request.kind.kind == "Pod"
input.request.operation == "CREATE"
input.request.object.spec.nodeSelector
not count(input.request.object.spec.nodeSelector) > 0
reason := "pod with nodeselector not allowed at the specified location"
```

Answer (score 0):

As was discussed in the [OPA contrib issue](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/contrib/issues/154), the problem was not with your policy but with flawed input data.